# How to check if a directory exist, within a shell script?

Tags: unix

What command can be used to check if a directory does or does not exist, within a shell script?

Comment: Next time, dear @ayyappa, have a look at the suggested older posts when you type your title ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -d "/path/to/dir" ]
then
      echo "Directory /path/to/dir exists."
else
      echo "Error: Directory /path/to/dir does not exists."
fi
```